# Modifying the webparts on a users mysite

Tags: sharepoint, mysite

I need the ability, as an administrator, to go to a users My Site and change the webparts they have.

I can seem to find a way in the UI or find anything from Google.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to change the My Site web parts for a single particular user, is to log in as that user.

1. Click "Welcome FirstName LastName" in the top-right corner of your SharePoint site.
2. Click "Sign in as a different user". Then fill in their credentials.
3. Click the "My Site" link in the top-right corner.
4. Adjust web parts as necessary.